# How can I concatenate two string columns in Pandas, but excluding repeated words from the second one?

Tags: python, pandas, string, character

Here's the thing, I have something like:

```
col1                          col2
This is a blue book           blue book above
This is a green ball          this is a ball
What is your name             blue book above
```

I want to create col3 like this:

```
col1                          col2                  col3
this is a blue book           blue book above       this is a blue book above
this is a green ball          this is a ball        this is a green ball
what is your name             blue book above       what is your name blue book above
```

I can't find a way to make this work

Comment: Does it matter what order the words are in, or is the condition just that if a word is in both col1 and col2 it should only be included in col3 once?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: This consists of several steps: concatenate two strings, break into words, de-dup the word lists, rejoin into a string, and create a new column with that value.  Where are you stuck?  What parts do you have working?  Post your code!

Comment: @Prune ok, sorry about that

Comment: @ChrisDoyle not so much, I would rather have in the order I mentioned, but that wouldn't break anything

Comment: but i mean if col one is "blue ball" and col2 is "ball blue" what should be the output of col3? just "blue ball"? I.E only concat words from col2 which are not in col 1?

Comment: what about duplicate words in the same column, you want to keep them? e.g. `col1='The blue book and the red book'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> concatenate two string columns in Pandas, but excluding repeated words
> from the second one

Try this:

```
def f(r):
  c1,c2 = r
  s1 = c1.split(" ")
  s2 = c2.split(" ")
  s3 = [s for s in s2 if s not in s1]
  return c1+" "+" ".join(s3)
df["col3"] = df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(f, axis=1)
df
                   col1               col2                               col3
0   this is a blue book    blue book above          this is a blue book above
1   this is a green ball    this is a ball               this is a green ball
2   what is your name      blue book above  what is your name blue book above
```